# Add suffix to v-axis google chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization, linechart

I have a Google Line Chart showing temperature over time. I can't figure out how to add a suffix to the v-axis values. I would like for the values (for example `10` on the v-axis) to say `10˚C`.

Does it exist a:

```
var option = {
vAxis: {}
}
```

for adding a suffix to values?
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution worked! :)

```
var option = {
  vAxis: {
     format: '#,##0˚C'
  }
}
```